# fancyBox: Scale Issue on Device / Orientation Rotate

Tags: android, jquery, fancybox

When using fancyBox, whether its an image or an iFrame (YouTube), and open this on a mobile device and then rotate (landscape to portrait or vice versa), fancyBox doesn't scale or fit to width of device window?

fancyBox Options:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers : {
                media: true,
                title: null

                },
            width       : 800,
            height      : 450,
            aspectRatio : true,
            scrolling   : 'no',
            openEffect  : 'fade',
            closeEffect : 'fade'
        });
    });
```

Device: SAM GALXY S3
OS: ANDROID 4.2
Browser: FF / CHRME / DOLPHIN

fancyBox version: 2.1.5 PACK

p.s. this is happening also on the examples, both versions 2 and beta! :/

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be setting a static width and height value for your fancy box. That's not a bad thing to do, but it does explain why your fancybox is not fitting the device screen: mobile devices tend to be less than 800px in width.

To fix this, you can easily use css styles to set max-widths for fancybox classes "fancybox-wrap" and "fancybox-inner".

Example:

```
.fancybox-wrap{max-width: 95%!important;}
.fancybox-inner {max-width: 100%!important;}
```

These rules use !important because they need to be able to overwrite the html width/height set by the fancybox options.

You can easily set the same styles using a jquery function to set css styles in fancybox's afterLoad option (though there may be more efficient methods to use than afterLoad, it should still get the job done.)

Comment: Thanks this is great it fixed my problem and I was able to target all my devices :)

https://jsfiddle.net/JudiNbrown/mcz2y6fp/3/
NOTE: This works on the live page, but not in the demo on js fiddle as the youtube video is blocked so you'll have to just copy the content if you want to test it